# Play Framework beginner. Scala.html error in compilation

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0

I am learning the Play framework and I am learning CRUD controllers. I want to make a form to add new posts but I have a compilation error. As I am new to scala I cannot figure out the error.

```
@(productForm: Form[Product])
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main("Product Form"){
<h1>Product Form</h1>

@helper.form(action = routes.Products.save()){
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product (@productForm("name").valueOr("New")) </legend>
        @helper.inputText(@productForm("ean"), '_label -> "EAN")
        @helper.inputText(@productForm("name"), '_label -> "Name")
        @helper.textarea(@productForm("description"), '_label -> "Description")
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
    <a class="btn" href="@routes.Products.index()">Cancel</a>
}
}
```

the error is:

```
/Users/andrei/Desktop/PlayFramework/app/views/products/details.scala.html:11: illegal start of simple expression
[error]             @helper.inputText(@productForm("ean"), '_label -> "EAN")
```

another problem:I define in the class a private static final variable, but I get an error. I think it's due to a deprecated library as I am learning the framework from a 2014 book

```
import play.api.data.Form; 
import play.api.FormFactory;
public class Products extends Controller {

Form<Product> productForm = formFactory.form(Product.class);
```

the error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable formFactory
location: class controllers.Products
```

source to documentation where I've found FormFactory:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you started the expression with `@`, than you do not need to use it before `productForm`, so

```
@helper.inputText(productForm("ean"), '_label -> "EAN")
```

should do the trick for you.

> The Scala template uses @ as the single special character. Every time
>   this character is encountered, it indicates the beginning of a dynamic
>   statement. You are not required to explicitly close the code block -
>   the end of the dynamic statement will be inferred from your code:

Comment: Thank you! this solved my problem! Can you check please the question? I've updated the question and added one more problem and maybe you could help to solve that

Comment: @xzayt, you should add another question. not add into the same one